# How to install screensavers on Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: kubuntu

I am using Kubuntu 18.04 for a year now.  I noticed that there are no screensaver settings to be found.  Has Ubuntu done away with screensavers?  It was useful and sometimes entertaining, I would like to be able to install it again.  Help please.

Comment: Not really needed with modern monitors but I'm sure you can install something. Just search for it in the software app.

Comment: See https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php/70788-Where-are-the-screensavers